# Command to Display the return type and arguments of the methods/functions of the shared library .so

Tags: shared-libraries

I wanted  Dumpbin /EXPORTS  equivalent in linux os for .so files

I tried using objdump, nm, readelf, but none of them gave me the complete declaration of the function exported by .so file.

I want to list the exported function with return type, argument types and its name...(not only the name)

Please help!

Comment: This information is not necessarily available in a shared library.

Comment: Yes.. I know .. but for the shared libraries build in debug mode